# Table design with "Person Number"

Tags: sql, identity, uniqueidentifier

We have a need to store people, with their 'Person Number' in the format the business uses them. At the moment, they use a manual process with numbers for the person in the format of, for example FP123456. The next person added gets the next number, so FP123457.

There is a search in the system based on that number.

My idea was to use the primary key as the numeric part, with an IDENTITY(123456,1), and then have a calculated column (somehow), which appends the current prefix (FP) to the primary key, giving FPxxxxxx

I was thinking of maybe using a default (If that's possible) on the PersonNumber column, which, on inserts, just does 'FP' + Id.

Is this a good idea, or are there possible issues? Also, how would I default the column, on insert. Maybe a trigger would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would certainly keep this *PersonNumber* separate from the [Primary Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key).

You will find folks who disagree, but in my experience using a [natural key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) as the primary key *always* turns out to be a bad choice. Things change*.

- Today you format the PersonNumber one way. Tomorrow you get a new boss with new ideas, and the format changes. Then you have the problem of updating not only the one original column "PersonNumber", you have to update foreign keys as well.
- Tomorrow you may need to [federate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_database_system), meaning share records across multiple databases or other systems. So you would have to change the way you do your primary key, such as using [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) values rather than integer values.
- At some point you may well need to rebuild your tables, involving exporting and importing your data. At that point you would want to keep your PersonNumber values but generate new primary key values.

Bottom line is that the job of generating a primary key may seem to be the same kind of job as generating PersonNumber, but they are really two different jobs. [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is a guiding principal to avoid brittle (easily broken) software. For example, if the PersonNumber generator gets messed up somehow, at least the rest of the database (primary keys in this table and foreign keys in related tables) would still continue to function.

So use a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) for the primary key. Then separately work out a strategy for managing the PersonNumber.

That strategy may involve the user interface or server-side app incrementing a number to generate the PersonNumber, as suggested by SDReyes on this page.

Another strategy is leveraging the database server to generate a sequence/serial for PersonNumber. If you have a serious database server such as MS SQL Server or [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org), you should be able to create a sequence/serial generator without being tied to a primary key. You can create a trigger that calls on that sequence generator to assign a default value for new records. A serious database server will be built to handle the concurrency problem pointed out by SDReyes so that the numbers are generated without duplicates. But read the doc, as some serial number generators may have gaps in the sequence, especially if a transaction rollback happens. If that is unacceptable, you may need to find another route.

---

*If you think this unlikely, ask a programmer or sysadmin with grey hair.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). You can index a persisted computed column.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD PersonNumber AS 'FP' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(15)) PERSISTED NOT NULL
go
```

[See SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1706/1)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recomend you to use a different autogenerated column as id, something like an int. why? because it's very efficient doing joins and let you, for example, change a Persons Number without breaking the integrity of your foreign references.

Another column, named 'person number' would contain such number (e.g. FP1337) with a uniqueness constraint.

Comment: So, are you saying to add a 'PersonNumber' column with auto incriment? But it would be a VARCHAR, though, no?

Comment: No, just add the column and let the UI to figure out the next valid ID. why, because generally the UI language (e.g. C#) let you write more intelligent and complex mechanisms than SQL.

For example, I could easily write a C# method to detect that even if I just used this id: FP900002, I should use FP000004 because it's not being used. or stopped being used for some reason.

Comment: And think of concurrency issues, 10 users registering people simultaneously, it's easier to make a cute UI using, pub/sub events and more complicated deferring the ID's assignation to the DB...

Comment: Concurrency is exactly at issue with your suggestion to generate the IDs in the client code. With that approach, two different app instances, reading the DB at the same time, would generate the same ID for two distinct people. Apparently, only one of them would succeed in saving the results, the other would have to catch the unique constraint violation exception and generate its ID anew. And what if another app managed to generate and save the very same new ID in the meantime?

Comment: I have been using that approach because it let you see in advance what ID the entity will use. sometimes that's quite helpful. for example, we use that in my gym, to reduce the time it takes to register a new user and give him his code to start using the equipment.

Comment: There are many ways to handle it, for example, you can use a concurrent dictionary (i love that class) or a redis collection with expiration dates. the main idea is to assign an id for a limit time and give it back to the pool if not used.

Comment: I'd do it that way. but you can go and use the db. it's simpler, but it's kinda difficult to show in advance the ID that the user being created will use.

Answer (score 0):

If your number is generated externally then just use it.  Sounds to me like you've already got your PK.  You're only going to get it wrong at some point in the future.

If you're suggesting that you need to generate them in the DB from now on then just use an IDENTITY and don't bother with the FP prefix - just take it off at the UI.

Comment: I was thinking about that - but, if they decide to use another prefex at some point in the future - it could be an issue. The answer would be, add a Prefix column, I guess. But then, the search may be slower? Searching for FP12345, we would need to strip the FP, search for 12345 and prefix = FP. I guess that's not too bad, and is an option being concidered,

Comment: Also, at the moment, it's manual, and a person gets the highest person number, and adds 1 to it, to get the new number. The new system is to be handled by the application (or DB), and will be totally automatic.

Comment: Presumably the prefix indicates some kind of "person type".  If that's the case you'll be able to derive the prefix from the other data.  To be honest though, without knowing your business or having a crystal ball I'd leave it for now and deal with it when you have to.  There's no real upside to manufacturing a prefix if you're generating the rest of it with an auto generated number.